# Language localization without using global variables?

Tags: c++, localization, c++20

Right now I am storing every string I use in my program in a header file like this:

```
#ifndef LANGUAGE_COMMON_H
#define LANGUAGE_COMMON_H


namespace global_lang { 
    
    inline std::string continue_on = "continue";
    inline std::string back = "back";
    
    inline std::string new_game = "New Game";
    inline std::string load_game = "Load Game";
    inline std::string settings = "Settings";
    inline std::string quit_game = "Escape";
    inline std::string enter_seed = "Enter Seed:";
    //etc...
}

#endif
```

This functions fine, but the problem is I can't change the value of the strings unless I edit the header file and recompile the program. This was just supposed to be a placeholder to keep all the strings in one place, but now I'm stumped on ways I can actually implement my idea.

What I'm envisioning is being able to call one function, for example:

```
global_lang::load_strings("french.xml");
```

Which will load new definitions for every string in the game. This can be used to translate the game into other languages, for mods, etc.

I can switch to using a localization library to solve the localization problem, but this won't address the problem of being able to modify the game. Essentially what I want to do is load every string of text used in the program from XML files so they can be easily modified by the end user.

The only way I could think of to do this is have some sort of global class object that stores and returns all the strings, but I'm not sure if that's a very good solution. Is there better way to accomplish what I'm wanting to do?

Comment: "some sort of global class object that stores and returns all the strings" seems like a totally reasonable solution to me.

Comment: I think you are wrong with "I can switch to using a localization library to solve the localization problem, but this won't address the problem of being able to modify the game.". Localization libraries are standardized, and you have a lot of tools, so people can modify/add languages easily (also by non programmers, and possibly just via web tools). Translators are often non-programmers, so editing a xml is a NO-NO for many of them.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to have a global class defined with static const fields for storing the variables, further make the constructor of this class private.

I personally feel putting constants in xml would be an overkill, although have seen code maintaining a config file (might depend on frequency of changes).